# how to input exponents during run time in c++

Tags: c++

Hey I have made a calculator which actually does my physics calculation,I have made it lesson wise so in this you have to select lesson then topic then the formula you want to use then finally input all the values then you get the answer but the problem is that, I have values like 2*10^-10. Which are in exponential form,so when I give values for calculation I have to type 0.0000000002 instead of 2*10^-10.
So how do I input a exponent as an exponent?

Answer (score 1):

Type 1.23e-4 instead of 0.000123.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notation with `e` and read the input into a `double` from an input stream like this (here the standard input):

```
double in;
std::cin >> in;
```